# nvd3 Chart Formatting on y-Axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, nvd3.js

Does anyone know of any inherent reductions that nvd3 does to y-values?  Data seems to be correct after a JSON.parse, and the dates on the x-values are correct, but the y-values are charted much lower than they were input.  Examples: the first y-value of 4.152 becomes 0 and 5.557 is graphed as 0.273, so it's not just subtracting the first y-value to start the chart at the origin.  Any insight is greatly appreciated.

The Chart code (in a separate .js file):

```
$(function () {
    // nvd3 charts
    tisa_nvd3_charts.cumulativeLine();
})

// nvd3 charts
tisa_nvd3_charts = {
    cumulativeLine: function () {
        if ($('#nvd3_cumulativeLine').length) {
            nv.addGraph(function () {
                var chart = nv.models.cumulativeLineChart()
                    .useInteractiveGuideline(true)
                    .x(function (d) { return d[0] })
                    .y(function (d) { return d[1] })
                    .color(d3.scale.category20().range())
                    .transitionDuration(500)
                    .clipVoronoi(false);

            chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function (d) {
                return d3.time.format('%m/%d/%y')(new Date(d))
            });

            chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format('$,.3f'));

            d3.select('#nvd3_cumulativeLine svg').datum(cumulativeTestData()).call(chart);

            nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

            return chart;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The .datum function in the View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function cumulativeTestData() {
        var closes = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Coordinates))')
        return [
            {
                key: "Closing Prices",
                mean: 60,
                values: closes
            },
        ];
    }
</script>
```

HTML of the correct JSON.parse:

```
var closes = JSON.parse('[[1367341200000,4.152],[1369933200000,4.148],[1375203600000,3.459],[1377882000000,3.567], etc.]')
```

**EDIT:**  Here is a working plunkr that shows the y-values of the data being graphed at incorrect y-axis points: plnkr.co/edit/enR6tKQmpKWxroVHDVOQ?p=preview

Comment: could you provide a fiddle or plunkr?

Comment: Thank you for replying!  I was beginning to think that nobody would.  I'm new to UI, so I loaded the code into a fiddle, but it doesn't seem to be working: http://jsfiddle.net/4jt5wLum/

Comment: I have made a working plunkr for you:http://plnkr.co/edit/enR6tKQmpKWxroVHDVOQ?p=preview, and i am not so sure i understand you question well.

Comment: Thank you very much!  The question is better illustrated in that plunkr: the test data y-values in the script.js cumulativeTestData() function all have values over zero, and yet the chart is graphing all of the y-values as less than zero, with the line never climbing out of the negatives and into the positives (e.g. the first data point, [1083297600000, 0.77078283705125] graphed as y = -0.985).  I would like to simply plot the correct x- and y-values of each data point such that they are plotted in the correct position.  Is there any reason the chart isn't properly rendering the y-values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going back to answer this.  The solution was very silly.  Changing the graph from cumulative line chart to regular line chart rendered the y-values correctly.  Examples of the available nvd3 charts can be found [here](http://nvd3.org/examples/index.html).